# php preg_match() inside multiple separator

Tags: php

I have string:

```
$data = "012.03.AB";
```

I want preg_match for:
012 = numeric & 3 digits
03 = numeric & 2 digits
AB = alphabet & 2 digits

This is my code:

```
$data = "012.03.AB";
preg_match("/[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}|\.([A-Z]{2})/", $data);
```

but not working

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more about what you are looking for here?

Comment: `([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{2})\.([A-Z]{2})`

Comment: I want check my variable, if before first dot [0-9]{3 digit}, between dot [0-9]{2 digits} And last [A-Z]{2 digits}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, your problems are:

- You have a loose `|` in the middle of your pattern
- Your second subpattern is set to be **3** digits, but you said it should be **2** digits
- (may or may not be on purpose) your pattern isn't anchored

---

```
if (preg_match('#^([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{2})\.([A-Z]{2})$#D', $data, $result) === 1) {
    // $data matched; you can use the segments as:
    $first  = (int) $result[1];
    $second = (int) $result[2];
    $third  =       $result[3];
} else {
    // $data did not match
}
```

You may want to add an `i` flag at the end if the 2 characters are allowed to be lowercase aswell.